# How to populate listbox dynamically with SQL values

Tags: c#, arrays, data-binding, listbox

I am a C# beginner. What I am trying to do is pull data from a column in a SQL database and write it to a listbox. Basically, I want the data in the part_num column of my table to be displayed dynamically in the listbox.

I have seen:

```
this.listParts.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Part1", "Part2"});
```

But how would I go about replacing “Part1” and “Part2” with dynamically generated values from SQL?

```
public mainForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(
        "Data Source=DBELL;Initial Catalog=part_table;Integrated Security=True");
    conn.Open();
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
        "SELECT part_num from customParts", conn);
         adapter.Fill(ds);
    foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)

        this.listParts.Items.AddRange(new object[] {"Part1", "Part2"});
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Bind directly to the DataTable. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w67sdsex.aspx    BTW as your SqlConnection implements IDisposable you should look at the using statement and also move your databinding code to its own method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02%28v=VS.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Why not use the `DataTable` as `DataSource`:

```
public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DBELL;Initial Catalog=part_table;Integrated Security=True");
            conn.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(
            "SELECT part_num from customParts", conn);
            adapter.Fill(ds);
            this.listParts.DataSource = ds.Tables[0]; 
            this.listParts.DisplayMember = "part_num"; 
        }
```

You should read up on `DataSets` or even better yet `EntityFramework` and data-binding.

Comment: OK this seems much simpler, but when I deploy it I see "System.Data.DataRowView" rather then database values. Do I have to convert something to a string?

Comment: You don't need to. Simply specify the DisplayMember, e.g. DisplayMember="part_num".

Comment: Ahh, looks like I accidentally cutoff part of the code. All working now, really appreciate the help!