# Insert sql data into listbox

Tags: sql, vb.net, winforms, listbox

When I run this code my `listbox` is empty.  What is the best way to get data from SQL and into a `listbox`?  When the form is submitted I want to use the `CustomreID` value data to store into another table and thought using the index would be the best solution.

```
sSQL = "SELECT CustomerID, Company from Customers Order by Company ASC"

cmd = New SqlCommand(sSQL, moConn)
rs = cmd.ExecuteReader()

While rs.Read
   lsbDestination.Items.Insert(CInt(rs("CustomerID")), rs("Company"))
End While
```

Comment: is this webform? or winforms?

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/a/9116889/1080742 and 
`lsbDestination.DisplayMember = "Company"; lsbDestination.ValueMember = "CustomerID";`

Comment: thanks displayMember and ValueMember are what I needed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily bind data to a ListBox using the `DataSource` property of the ListBox.  Try something like this (untested):

```
Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
Dim ds As New DataSet
adapter.Fill(ds)

lsbDestination.DataTextField = "Company"
lsbDestination.DataValueField = "CustomerId"
lsbDestination.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
lsbDestination.DataBind()
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a items to `ListBox` using *`While rs.Read`*.

```
Using rsAs SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
    While rs.Read()
        Dim items As Object() = {r("CustomerID"), r("Company").ToString()}
        listBox1.Items.Add(items)
    End While
    listBox1.DisplayMember = "Company"
    listBox1.ValueMember = "CustomerID"
End Using
```

Just let me know if you've encountered some problem.